# Sufficient Condition on the existence of an intersection between N spheres

Tags: spheres

I have this problem to solve:

Given N spheres with centers C : {$c_1, ..., c_n| c_i ∈ R^M$} and radiuses R : {$r_1, ..., r_n| r_i ∈ R$}

I'm searching for a sufficient condition which states that exists a region that is part of each sphere.

For N = 2 the condition is simple: if the euclidean distance d($c_1, c_2$) < $r_1 + r_2$ then the region exists

For N > 2 I have difficult both finding a sufficient condition myself or finding it online

Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  In order for MathJax commands to be effective, they must be surrounded by `$` signs.  For example, `$x^2$` shows up as $x^2$.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't knew the syntax

Comment: By [Helly's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helly%27s_theorem), in the plane it's enough to do the $N=3$ case, and in $\mathbb{R}^n$ it's enough to do the $N=n+1$ case. Even the case of three disks in the plane doesn't seem to be easy.  I found this [paper](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.989.1088&rep=rep1&type=pdf) on computing the area of the overlap.  It might have something useful in it.